# What iOS pod uses SCRCException in PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReaderCore.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My app has been rejected.

Reason given by Apple team is that my app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

> PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReaderCore.framework (SCRCException)￼

I haven't used any non public api in my application. But I have used some third party pods which are following.

1. pod 'Alamofire'
2. pod 'SwiftyJSON'
3. pod 'DataCache'
4. pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
5. pod 'LLSimpleCamera', '~> 4.1'
6. pod 'Clarifai'
7. pod 'SwiftMessages'
8. pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
9. pod 'Fabric'
10. pod 'Crashlytics'
11. pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 10.2.0'
12. pod 'GrowingTextView'

Anyone have any idea about that from above pods library which one is using non public api? I searched a lot but not getting anything. First two version of my app is already approved and its lived but this time its rejected.

Comment: What pods were different between this release and the last version(s)? Perhaps that would help narrow it down (though it may not be foolproof, if Apple missed a non-public API last time).

Comment: Is there an automated submission process where a non-public API usage can be detected?

Comment: No new pods added for this latest release. 
We also asked query to apple team and they answered like this .
Class "SCRCException" was found to be referenced in -[TFApplicationReader visit:]

TFApplicationReader is also not used in app code

Comment: Are you using TestFairy SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Ey folks. I received the same rejection. Looking at my project...

myMac: iosdeveloper$ grep -r "SCRC*" .

Binary file ./TestFairySDK/libTestFairy.a matches

Binary file ./Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols matches

https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReaderCore.framework

looks like testFairy and Fabric are the best candidates for that issue

Comment: Hi LittleBoat,
Did your app got apporved after remove the Testfairy and Fabric framework?